# Proof tautology With and Without Truth Tables

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that $(P\land Q)\to(P\lor Q)$ is a tautology without the use of truth tables.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Following the [natural deduction system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_2._Natural_deduction_system):

$$\begin{array}{cccl}
p \wedge q & (1) & p \wedge q & \text{(premise)} \\
p \wedge q & (2) & p & \text{(conj elim (1))} \\
p \wedge q & (3) & p \vee q & \text{(disj intro (2))} \\
\varnothing & (4) & ( p \wedge q ) \rightarrow ( p \vee q ) & \text{(cond proof (3))}
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

The following deduction is based on a truth table. T means true and F means false.

[image]

Comment: Nice illustration...+1

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This was done using Fitch. Assume the statement you want to prove is false. Start a new subproof where you show that $P\wedge Q$ implies $P\lor Q$. This produces a contradiction which allows you to negate your original assumption, proving $(P\land Q)\to (P\lor Q)$. Since this can be can be proved from no premises, the statement is a tautology.

Comment: You should delete everything in this proof except lines 3 through 6.